# Is "to reprove" a synonym for "to vindicate"?

Tags: synonyms

I cannot understand the meaning of the word **reproved** in the following verse of King James Bible:

> And unto Sarah he said, Behold, I have given thy brother a thousand
>   pieces of silver: behold, he is to thee a covering of the eyes, unto
>   all that are with thee, and with all other: thus she was **reproved**. - *Gen. 20:16 AV*

I looked **to reprove** up in dictionaries and found that this verb has negative connotations, meaning **to condemn**, **to scold**, **to censure**, etc.

Not sure about the meaning of the verse, I referred to another translation - English Standard Version - and it seems to have apparently opposite meaning:

> To Sarah he said, "Behold, I have given your brother a thousand pieces
>   of silver. It is a sign of your innocence in the eyes of all who are
>   with you, and before everyone you are **vindicated**." - *Gen. 20:16 ESV*

According to this Sarah was **vindicated**, i.e. **exonerated** or **absolved**.

I wonder how these two translations of the same passage can be interchangeable. And if they can is "to reprove" a synonym for "to vindicate"?

Comment: This question is probably better asked on [Biblical Hermeneutics](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: The problem with this question is that both versions depended on new translations, so it is quite possible that 2 different translators 400 years apart from each other found a different interpretation, and  this is not really a question about English. On the other hand, it is possible that "reproved" had another meaning 400 years ago.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question about translations, not the meanings of words in English.